# Android Phone with Long Battery Life under Heavy Data Usage

Tags: smartphones, android, mobile-phone

I tend to use my phone as almost a mini-laptop. What that means is, I use a lot of data whether it's web browsing, looking at funny pictures, streaming music/videos, using Skype, etc.

On my previous phone (an iPhone), intense data usage can drain my battery at a rate as fast as 20%/hour. This means that I can only use my phone for 5 hours.

Thus, I am looking for recommendations for a functionally high end Android phone with emphasis on battery life.

More specifically, it should:

- Run any reasonably programmed Android app/games without any noticeable slow down.
- Fits in my pocket,

  - In fact, I think the iPhone 6 is too big. I actually prefer a size smaller than that. But as long as it can fit in my pocket I'm fine.
- Can sustain for as long as possible (preferably 24 hour) under intense data usage.
- Is actually a phone. (i.e. can make calls, send text, etc.)

Anything else is a bonus, but do please let me know if there are any major caveats. (e.g. if the phone typically dies in 1 month, let me know about that..)

Comment: Any specifications on the country and carrier? I am looking at the specs of Kyocera Brigadier, but it seems to only be available through Verizon in the US

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is likely to be to get either a smartphone with interchangeable batteries and carry multiple ones, or get an external power pack.

A [limited sample size](http://www.trustedreviews.com/opinions/which-phone-has-the-best-battery-life) survey of a number of smartphones show that for web browsing, the best performer (iPhone 6) drained 35% battery in 150 minutes, which implies a 7.5 hour battery life for web browsing over WiFi. Since data using the cellular radio [consumes more battery life](http://www.androidcentral.com/shutting-wi-fi-it-worth-it) than WiFi, it would likely have even lower battery life (which matches the 5 hours you are getting on a full charge). Therefore, it is highly unlikely any existing smartphone has >24h of battery life on mobile data.

A power pack such as [this one](http://www.mi.com/sg/powerbank/) can provide enough power for continuous web usage. Assuming the same iPhone 6, the 16000mAh model can provide power for over 30 hours straight, or you can reduce the capacity if you want to carry less battery weight around. The battery pack weighs around ~400g on its own, and would not fit inside an average pocket, but if you are on the go (eg on a train/bus without a power socket, or on a bicycle), it would be a good idea.

Comment: +1 for interchangeable batteries. I did this with my Samsung phone. With two extra batteries and an external charger, you're fine. The batteries are actually quite slim and not a hassle at all to bring around. And it removes the trouble of the bulky power pack.

Comment: Speaking of interchangable batteries, anker makes an extended battery case for the samsung s3 that's like 3x the battery capacity

Answer (score 3):

Sony's [Xperia Z3 Compact](http://www.androidcentral.com/sony-xperia-z3-z3-compact-review) and [Xperia Z5 Compact](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9596/sony-launches-the-xperia-z5-z5-compact-and-z5-premium-with-uhd-display) are about the same size as the iPhone 6 (not plus). They also seem to be the only (as of beginning of Oct, 2015) high end Android devices with screens under 5 inches. Sony's Z3 and Z3 compact have some very excellent [battery life](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2402573) compared to other Android manufacturers. The Z5 compact is expected to be released in October, and thus has not been reviewed yet. It does use the very hot Snapdragon 810, so it remains to be seen if the extra 100 maH (to 2700 mAh) in the battery is enough to last as long as the Snapdragon 801 and 2600 mAh battery in the Z3 Compact. Both the Z3 Compact and the Z5 compact have non-removable batteries, so if you need more life than they provide, you'll have to use an external solution rather than swapping the internal batteries.

Note that in general, larger phones' battery life will be less affected by radio usage than smaller phones, because more of the power drain shifts to power the display, reducing the *relative* amount used by the radio.

Answer (score 0):

The huawei marathon m5 is the company's new offering with 5000mah which should have enough juice to last you around 7-9 hrs of web browsing

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [UleFone Power](http://ulefone.com/products/power/features.html), which is my second UleFone and I am more than happy with both.

It has a 6,500 mAH battery and gives me up to 5 days between charges.

HOWEVER, I am not a heavy data user like you.

That said, you ought to be able to get a full day's use from it. It is reasonably priced, so well worth trying. Let us know what you think

Answer (score -1):

You could try the [Lenovo P2](http://shop.lenovo.com/be/nl/smartphones/lenovo/lenovo-p2/).

Great phone with great battery life and not draining the bank..